# Is there a name for circles that show progress through form?

Tags: interface, human-interface-guideline

Interfaces that guide users through several steps with one per screen per step often have little circles at the bottom of the page, with each circle representing a step/screen in the sequence. The active circle indicates the number of steps/screen the user has already completed.

Is there a name for this design pattern? I'd like to read more about best practices in this area (the max number of circles / distinct screens that hold user attention, size of circles, interaction patterns, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Dot navigation

#### Horizontal dot navigation

> Series of icons in the top or bottom of a content frame:

- Show how many elements or steps there are
- In a simple element content, allows easily jump from one content to another by clicking on the icon

#### Vertical dot navigation

> Series of icons in the left or right sidebar with two main features:

- Indicate the number of pages
- Allow users to easily browse the page by clicking on each icon

[image]

## Progress Trackers

> Progress trackers (or progress indicators) display progress through a sequence by breaking it up into multiple logical and numbered steps. They guide the user through a number of steps in order to complete a specified task. Good progress tracker should inform users about following aspects:

- What steps (or tasks) they have completed (preferably with a proper
  visual response)
- Current step they are on (user’s current location within the
  process)
- Which and how many steps still remain (preferably with clear
  designation)

[image: Progress Trackers]

<sub>*Sources [bashooka.com](https://bashooka.com/inspiration/single-page-websites-with-dot-navigation/), [tympanus.net](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/21/dot-navigation-styles/), [uxplanet.org](https://uxplanet.org/progress-trackers-in-ux-design-4319cef1c600)*</sub>

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is a variation of the [Progress Indicator/Completeness meter](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/CompletenessMeter/examples) that you are referring to, and there is a general description of the UI pattern that talks about the problem and provides examples of potential solutions to the design problem.

Often this is implemented as a series of circles at the top of the screen or along the left/right hand side of the page, but I actually haven't seen them at the bottom of the page.

I wouldn't think that the styling of the progress indicator affects the terminology applied to it (at least from a UX design point of view), but perhaps there are differences when it comes to the visual design perspective.

Comment: Ah yes, it's a discretized version of the continuous progress meter. Here's an example of the circles idea: https://dribbble.com/shots/4020266-Period-Tracker-Onboarding In your experience, can users generally click the individual circles to navigate to the ith route / screen?